# Singly linked list pseudo-code sum specific elements

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity, pseudocode, singly-linked-list

I wrote some pseudo-code for a singly linked list.  The function should increase each occurrence of the key (k) by the value of the previous element's key, the only exception is the 1st element (which is unchanged).

```
List-Increase-Key(L,k)
    x = L.head
    k = L.head
    while (x.key != k and x != NIL)
        prex = x.key
        x = x.next
        if x.key == k
            x.key = x.key + prex
```

I think the running time is O(n), since it traverses the whole list once.  I'm wondering if my time complexity estimate is accurate, or if this is more/less efficient than that.  Or if you think my idea is junk and will crash and burn horribly.  Thanks for stopping by.

Comment: " Or if you think my idea is junk and will crash and burn horribly. " Are you inside the Matrix !

Answer (score 0):

The running time is clearly O(n),since a single traversal is done.

But i find some Disparities in your code.

```
while (x.key != k and x != NIL)
```

In above statement ,the NIL check should precede the condition **"x.key!=k"**.

Comment: Spandan you know, I'm wondering if it's not more accurate to call this Ɵ(n) since best and worst case times are n.  Good call on switching the NIL condition.